# How to Propagate JS Code Changes to Chrome in a Blazor WebAssembly App in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome-devtools, blazor

As the title indicates, I am writing in Visual Studio (community 2019) a Blazor WebAssembly app that contains JavaScript (and TypeScript). Sometimes, when I make code changes to the js and then run under the debugger, the old version of the js code is still being used by Chrome (v16.6.1 if memory serves) as shown using their devtools. I have searched endlessly for a way to force the changed file to load, but no luck so far.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.  Steve